# iOS GLSL. Is There A Way To Create An Image Histogram Using a GLSL Shader?

Tags: ios, image-processing, glsl, histogram

Elsewhere on StackOverflow a question was asked regarding a depthbuffer histogram - [Create depth buffer histogram texture with GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647727/create-depth-buffer-histogram-texture-with-glsl).

I am writing an iOS image-processing app and am intrigued by this question but unclear on the answer provided.  So, is it possible to create an image histogram using the GPU via GLSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's not clearly the best approach, but it's indeed the best one available in iOS, since OpenCL is not supported. You'll lose elegance, and your code will probably not as straightforward, but almost all OpenCL features can be achieved with shaders.

If it helps, DirectX11 comes with a FFT example for compute shaders. See DX11 August SDK Release Notes.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure that article is relevant? Where in there do they calculate a histogram using a shader?

Comment: I only pointed because it touched both topics, and put this very same thing in bold, saying that it only was to get him started. Maybe it was a bad idea, even after stating it. Should I delete it?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't something I was missing in that article. I've been working on an OpenGL ES shader-based histogram implementation myself, but nothing in that article comes close to what I've been doing, so I thought I might have missed some detail. If it's just a broad reference to GLSL being used for something, that probably won't help at all in this case. Tommy's answer in the above-linked question is a far better place to start. I'll answer when I have my own implementation working right.

Comment: I'm trying to prepare a simple sample.

Comment: have you guys able to do anything ? I am also struggling to achieve this

Answer (score 36):

Yes, there is, although it's a little more challenging on iOS than you'd think. This is a red histogram generated and plotted entirely on the GPU, running against a live video feed:

[image: GPU red histogram]

[Tommy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647931/19679) in the question you link is a great starting point, as is [this paper by Scheuermann and Hensley](http://www.shaderwrangler.com/publications/histogram/histogram_cameraready.pdf). What's suggested there is to use scattering to build up a histogram for color channels in the image. Scattering is a process where you pass in a grid of points to your vertex shader, and then have that shader read the color at that point. The value of the desired color channel at that point is then written out as the X coordinate (with 0 for the Y and Z coordinates). Your fragment shader then draws out a translucent, 1-pixel-wide point at that coordinate in your target.

That target is a 1-pixel-tall, 256-pixel-wide image, with each width position representing one color bin. By writing out a point with a low alpha channel (or low RGB values) and then using additive blending, you can accumulate a higher value for each bin based on the number of times that specific color value occurs in the image. These histogram pixels can then be read for later processing.

The major problem with doing this in shaders on iOS is that, despite [reports to the contrary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6754705/19679), Apple clearly states that texture reads in a vertex shader will not work on iOS. I tried this with all of my iOS 5.0 devices, and none of them were able to perform texture reads in a vertex shader (the screen just goes black, with no GL errors being thrown).

To work around this, I found that I could read the raw pixels of my input image (via `glReadPixels()` or the [faster texture caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704392/19679)) and pass those bytes in as vertex data with a GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE type. The following code accomplishes this:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, inputTextureSize.width, inputTextureSize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vertexSamplingCoordinates);

[self setFilterFBO];

[filterProgram use];

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glVertexAttribPointer(filterPositionAttribute, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, (_downsamplingFactor - 1) * 4, vertexSamplingCoordinates);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, inputTextureSize.width * inputTextureSize.height / (CGFloat)_downsamplingFactor);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

In the above code, you'll notice that I employ a stride to only sample a fraction of the image pixels. This is because the lowest opacity or greyscale level you can write out is 1/256, meaning that each bin becomes maxed out once more than 255 pixels in that image have that color value. Therefore, I had to reduce the number of pixels processed in order to bring the range of the histogram within this limited window. I'm looking for a way to extend this dynamic range.

The shaders used to do this are as follows, starting with the vertex shader:

```
 attribute vec4 position;

 void main()
 {
     gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (position.x * 0.0078125), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     gl_PointSize = 1.0;
 }
```

and finishing with the fragment shader:

```
 uniform highp float scalingFactor;

 void main()
 {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(scalingFactor);
 }
```

A working implementation of this can be found in my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework. Grab and run the FilterShowcase example to see the histogram analysis and plotting for yourself.

There are some performance issues with this implementation, but it was the only way I could think of doing this on-GPU on iOS. I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Very cool. Just a small nit-pick: the value `0.0078125` offsets the value bins by one grayvalue. Using (2.0/255.0 = 0.00784313725) maps 255 to 2 (before subtraction of 1).