# numpy / linear algebra - fast 16-bit histogram

Tags: numpy, histogram, linear-algebra

If I have an image made of uint16s and want to compute a histogram for each bit, i.e. a vector 'x' of `0..65535` that contains the intensity value, and a vector `y` that is the number of samples that have that value, is there a vectorized numpy / linear algreba way to compute this?

Comment: Wonder if creating histogram by itself can be vectorized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985949/methods-to-vectorise-histogram-in-simd

Comment: Why can't you use `numpy.histogram()` or `numpy.unique(return_counts=True)` ?

Comment: The latter does what I want.  `np.hist` can be extremely slow for large images.

Comment: What are the height and width (in pixels) of your large images please?

Comment: 2560x2160, 16-bit per channel x 4 channels.

Comment: Please have another look - I have updated my answer with a significant speedup.

Comment: would be great not to need such a mammoth dependency as opencv for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did it the obvious way with Numpy, and using your image dimensions on my Mac, it takes 300ms. I then did the same thing with OpenCV and it is 33x faster at 9ms!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Dimensions - height, width
h, w = 2160, 2560

# Known image, channel0=1, channel1=3, channel2=5, channel3=65535
R =  np.zeros((h,w,4), dtype=np.uint16)
R[...,0] = 1
R[...,1] = 3
R[...,2] = 5
R[...,3] = 65535

def npHistogram(R):
    """Generate histogram using Numpy"""
    H, _ = np.histogram(R,65536)
    return H

def OpenCVHistogram(R):
    """Generate histogram using OpenCV"""
    H = cv2.calcHist([R.ravel()], [0], None, [65536], [0,65536]) 
    return H

A = npHistogram(R)
B = OpenCVHistogram(R)

#%timeit npHistogram(R)
#%timeit OpenCVHistogram(R)
```

**Results**

Using IPython, I got these timings

```
%timeit npHistogram(R)
300 ms ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit OpenCVHistogram(R)
9.02 ms ± 226 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Keywords**: Python, histogram, slow, Numpy, np.histogram, speedup, OpenCV, image processing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if **OpenCV** is too big a dependency for you to get 9ms processing time instead of 300ms, how about **Numba**? This runs in 10ms.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# Dimensions - height, width
h, w = 2160, 2560

# Known image, channel0=1, channel1=3, channel2=5, channel3=65535
R =  np.zeros((h,w,4), dtype=np.uint16)
R[...,0] = 1
R[...,1] = 3
R[...,2] = 5
R[...,3] = 65535

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def NumbaHistogram(pixels):
    """Histogram of uint16 image"""
    H = np.zeros(65536, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(len(pixels)):
        H[pixels[i]] += 1
    return H

#%timeit q = NumbaHistogram(R.ravel())
```

**Results**

```
%timeit NumbaHistogram(R.ravel())                                                                                                                  
10.4 ms ± 54.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Numba is arguably worse.  The resistance to OpenCV is that getting it installed and linked properly can be a huge pain in the butt.  Numba is virtually impossible without using Conda as your python distribution, which is neither better nor worse.

Comment: Mmm, there's no pleasing some people  This explains why I like macOS, both OpenCV and Numba are one-liners to install, without Conda. I guess there's no point making a Cython version either.

Comment: I also use a Mac, but I have Windows and Linux users, too ;)