# race condition using OpenMP atomic capture operation for 3D histogram of particles and making an index

Tags: c++, multithreading, histogram, openmp, atomic

I have a piece of code in my full code:

```
const unsigned int GL=8000000;
const int cuba=8;
const int cubn=cuba+cuba;
const int cub3=cubn*cubn*cubn;
int Length[cub3];
int Begin[cub3];
int Counter[cub3];
int MIndex[GL];
struct Particle{
  int ix,jy,kz;
  int ip;
};
Particle particles[GL];
int GetIndex(const Particle & p){return (p.ix+cuba+cubn*(p.jy+cuba+cubn*(p.kz+cuba)));}    
...
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<cub3; ++i) Length[i]=Counter[i]=0;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
  int ic=GetIndex(particles[i]);
  #pragma omp atomic update
  Length[ic]++;
}
Begin[0]=0;
#pragma omp single
for(int i=1; i<cub3; ++i) Begin[i]=Begin[i-1]+Length[i-1];
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
  if(particles[i].ip==3)
  {
    int ic=GetIndex(particles[i]);
    if(ic>cub3 || ic<0) printf("ic=%d out of range!\n",ic);
    int cnt=0;
  #pragma omp atomic capture
    cnt=Counter[ic]++;
    MIndex[Begin[ic]+cnt]=i;
  }
}
```

If to remove

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

the code works properly and the output results are always the same.
But with this pragma there is some undefined behaviour/race condition in the code, because each time it gives different output results.
How to fix this issue?

Update: The task is the following. Have lots of particles with some random coordinates. Need to output to the array *MIndex* the indices in the array *particles* of the particles, which are in each cell (cartesian cube, for example, 1×1×1 cm) of the coordinate system. So, in the beginning of *MIndex* there should be the indices in the array *particles* of the particles in the 1st cell of the coordinate system, then - in the 2nd, then - in the 3rd and so on. The order of indices within given cell in the area *MIndex* is not important, may be arbitrary. If it is possible, need to make this in parallel, may be using atomic operations.

There is a straight way: to traverse across all the coordinate cells in parallel and in each cell check the coordinates of all the particles. But for large number of cells and particles this seems to be slow. Is there a faster approach? Is it possible to travel across the *particles* array only once in parallel and fill *MIndex* array using atomic operations, something like written in the code piece above?

Comment: Based on your updated information, if `Begin[ic]` is properly set up, then `MIndex[Begin[ic]+cnt]=i;` always points to a different memory location. So, the `Counter` array should be always the same, but the order of elements in `MIndex` is different. I do not see any data race/undefined behavior in your OpenMP code, it should give proper results. The only possible issue is its performance due to false sharing. How elements of `Begin` is calculated?

Comment: I collect the number of particles in voxel number i as Number[i] in parallel using #pragma omp atomic and then sequentially fill in Begin as: Begin[0]=0; for(int i=0; i<cub3; ++i){Begin[i]=Begin[i-1]+Number[i-1];}

Comment: Can you update your post and show us this code as well?

Comment: Updated my answer with an algorithm that should allow the final scattering to be parallelized (manually), as well as the initial histogram which is relatively easy.

Comment: Note that 1) `if(particles[i].ip==3)` (and bounds check) is missing when you calculate `Lenght`, 2) `ic==cub3` is also out of range, 3) When `ic` is out of range you should stop your calculation 3) `#pragma omp single` has no effect as it is not inside a parallel region., 4) Your OpenMP code should give the same result (but in different order) as serial code, but it is not very efficient (details are explained by @Peter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can't get a compiler to *auto*-parallelize scalar code for you if you want an algorithm that can work efficiently (without needing atomic RMWs on shared counters which would be a disaster, see below).  But you might be able to use OpenMP as a way to start threads and get thread IDs.

#### Keep per-thread count arrays from the initial histogram, use in 2nd pass

(Update: this might not work: I didn't notice the `if(particles[i].ip==3)` in the source before.  I was assuming that `Count[ic]` will go as high as `Length[ic]` in the serial version.  If that's not the case, this strategy might leave gaps or something.
But as Laci points out, perhaps you want that check when calculating Length in the first place, then it would be fine.)

Manually multi-thread the first histogram (into `Length[]`), with each thread working on a known range of `i` values.  Keep those per-thread lengths around, even as you sum across them and prefix-sum to build Begin[].

So `Length[thread][ic]` is the number of particles in that cube, out of the range of `i` values that this thread worked on.  (And will loop over again in the 2nd loop: the key is that we divide the particles between threads the same way twice.  Ideally with the same thread working on the same range, so things may still be hot in L1d cache.)

**Pre-process that into a per-thread `Begin[][]` array,** so each thread knows where in MIndex to put data from each bucket.

```
// pseudo-code, fairly close to actual C
for(ic < cub3) {
   // perhaps do this "vertical" sum into a temporary array
   // or prefix-sum within Length before combining across threads?
   int pos = sum(Length[0..nthreads-1][ic-1]) + Begin[0][ic-1];

   Begin[0][ic] = pos;
   for (int t = 1 ; t<nthreads ; t++) {
       pos += Length[t][ic];   // prefix-sum across threads for this cube bucket
       Begin[t][ic] = pos;
   }
}
```

This has a pretty terrible cache access pattern, especially with `cuba=8` making `Length[t][0]` and `Length[t+1][0]` 4096 bytes apart from each other.  (So 4k aliasing is a possible problem, as are cache conflict misses).

Perhaps each thread can prefix-sum its own slice of Length into that slice of Begin, 1. for cache access pattern (and locality since it just wrote those Lengths), and 2. to get some parallelism for that work.

Then in the final loop with `MIndex`, each thread can do `int pos = --Length[t][ic]` to derive a unique ID from the Length.  (Like you were doing with `Count[]`, but without introducing another per-thread array to zero.)

Each element of Length will return to zero, because the same thread is looking at the same points it just counted.  With correctly-calculated `Begin[t][ic]` positions, `MIndex[...] = i` stores won't conflict.  *False* sharing is still possible, but it's a large enough array that points will tend to be scattered around.

**Don't overdo it with number of threads**, especially if `cuba` is greater than 8.  The amount of Length / Begin pre-processing work scales with number of threads, so it may be better to just leave some CPUs free for unrelated threads or tasks to get some throughput done.   OTOH, with `cuba=8` meaning each per-thread array is only 4096 bytes (too small to parallelize the zeroing of, BTW), it's really not that much.

---

(Previous answer before your edit made it clearer what was going on.)

Is this basically a histogram?  If each thread has its own array of counts, you can sum them together at the end (you might need to do that manually, not have OpenMP do it for you).  But it seems you also need this count to be unique within each voxel, to have MIndex updated properly?  That might be a showstopper, like requiring adjusting every MIndex entry, if it's even possible.

After your update, you *are* doing a histogram into Length[], so that part can be sped up.

---

#### Atomic RMWs would be necessary for your code as-is, performance disaster

Atomic increments of shared counters would be slower, and on x86 might destroy the memory-level parallelism too badly.  On x86, every atomic RMW is also a full memory barrier, draining the store buffer before it happens, and blocking later loads from starting until after it happens.

As opposed to a single thread which can have cache misses to multiple `Counter`, `Begin` and `MIndex` elements outstanding, using non-atomic accesses.  (Thanks to out-of-order exec, the next iteration's load / inc / store for `Counter[ic]++` can be doing the load while there are cache misses outstanding for `Begin[ic]` and/or for `Mindex[]` stores.)

ISAs that allow relaxed-atomic increment might be able to do this efficiently, like AArch64.  (Again, OpenMP might not be able to do that for you.)

Even on x86, with *enough* (logical) cores, you might still get some speedup, especially if the `Counter` accesses are scattered enough they cores aren't constantly fighting over the same cache lines.  You'd still get a lot of cache lines bouncing between cores, though, instead of staying hot in L1d or L2.  (False sharing is a problem,

Perhaps software prefetch can help, like `prefetchw` (write-prefetching) the counter for 5 or 10 `i` iterations later.

---

**It wouldn't be deterministic which point went in which order**, even with `memory_order_seq_cst` increments, though.  Whichever thread increments `Counter[ic]` first is the one that associates that `cnt` with that `i`.

---

#### Alternative access patterns

**Perhaps have each thread scan *all* points, but only process a subset of them, with disjoint subsets.**  So the set of `Counter[]` elements that any given thread touches is *only* touched by that thread, so the increments can be non-atomic.

Filtering by `p.kz` ranges maybe makes the most sense since that's the largest multiplier in the indexing, so each thread "owns" a contiguous range of `Counter[]`.

But if your points aren't uniformly distributed, you'd need to know how to break things up to approximately equally divide the work.  And you can't just divide it more finely (like OMP schedule dynamic), since *each* thread is going to scan through *all* the points: that would multiply the amount of filtering work.

Maybe a couple fixed partitions would be a good tradeoff to gain *some* parallelism without introducing a lot of extra work.

---

#### Re: your edit

You already loop over the whole array of points doing `Length[ic]++;`? Seems redundant to do the same histogramming work again with `Counter[ic]++;`, but not obvious how to avoid it.

The count arrays are small, but if you don't need both when you're done, you could maybe just decrement Length to assign unique indices to each point in a voxel. At least the first histogram could benefit from parallelizing with different count arrays for each thread, and just vertically adding at the end. Should scale perfectly with threads since the count array is small enough for L1d cache.

BTW, **`for() Length[i]=Counter[i]=0;` is too small to be worth parallelizing**. For `cuba=8`, it's `8*8*16 * sizeof(int)` = 4096 bytes, just one page, so it's just two small memsets.

(Of course if each thread has their own separate Length array, they each need to zero it). That's small enough to even consider [unrolling with maybe 2 count arrays per thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985949/methods-to-vectorise-histogram-in-simd) to hide store/reload serial dependencies if a long sequence of points are all in the same bucket.  Combining count arrays at the end is a job for `#pragma omp simd` or just normal auto-vectorization with `gcc -O3 -march=native` since it's integer work.

For the final loop, **you could split your points array in half** (assign half to each thread), and have one thread get unique IDs by counting down from `--Length[i]`, and another counting up from 0 in `Counter[i]++`.  With different threads looking at different points, this could give you a factor of 2 speedup.  (Modulo contention for MIndex stores.)

To do more than just count up and down, you'd need info you don't have from just the overall Length array... but which you did have temporarily.  See the section at the top

Answer (score 3):

You are right to make the update `Counter[ic]++` atomic, but there is an additional problem on the next line: `MIndex[Begin[ic]+cnt]=i;` Different iterations can write into the same location here, unless you have mathematical proof that this is never the case from the structure of `MIndex`. So you have to make that line atomic too. And then there is almost no parallel work left in your loop, so your speed up if probably going to be abysmal.

EDIT the second line however is not of the right form for an atomic operation, so you have to make it `critical`. Which is going to make performance even worse.

Also, @Laci is correct that since this is an overwrite statement, the order of parallel scheduling is going to influence the outcome. So either live with that fact, or accept that this can not be parallelized.

Comment: I think using atomic operation will not solve the OP's problem, because the result depends on the order of loop executed.

Comment: I can't write #pragma acc atomic update above this line, as You wrote. The compiler curses: "Illegal operation in atomic expression".

Comment: I tried to put all these 2 lines in the structured block ({..}) below the #pragma omp atomic capture, but the result is the same: undefined behaviour/race condition.

Comment: See edit. Also: @Laci you're right that this algorithm is either undetermined or unparallelizable.

Comment: @And please read the documentation of `atomic`. There can only be one instruction, and it needs to have a specific form, or two statements that relate to each in very specific ways. Example: `v = x; x+=1`.

Comment: I can't use #pragma omp critical. The result must be the array of indices, but their order may be different, depending on th order of OpenMP threads being executed, I understand.

Comment: My task is simple. Have millions of particles with some coordinates. Need to output the indices of particles which are in each coordinate cell (for example, 1×1×1 cm) to the array MIndex sequentially (in the array MIndex) for each cell (in the beginning of MIndex, there are indices of the particles in the 1st cell, then in the 2nd, then in the 3rd and so on). The order of the indices within a cell in MIndex array is not important. Need to do this in parallel, if possible. This piece of code of code was my attempt to do this.

Comment: The alternative is to traverse across all the coordinate cells in parallel and in each cell check the coordinates of all the particles. But this seems to me to be rather slow if there are lots of cells and particles.