# Why is computing the histogram of a sorted array slower?

Tags: c++, performance, x86, histogram, cpu-architecture

Consider this code [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIABsGqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BfgF2mA6Z9Y0ExRHRsQlJCg1NLbntY32hA2VDiQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CbbbmLAJIQILCfYJhoAgjt7B5jHp8gIxAKot/dPZl2DH2XiOJzcyFG%2BF%2B2zuj2ewNe7zco2IoWAf3hgJeoLe4IAbp0iMRMU94QBWKyU4AMLwgEAMVChWizEzkgAibPZh1GTEcyEO%2BKZ6EOCDwo1QwGIrAgoQIhzQDFGhwAVExSIc5YcGBqtSqEItjgB2KyPQ6HfjEQ6ywSa97cjQnCx28Hap3HSzWPCLf7m80INkWJiBvBcsOez3bU1PI2c%2BEUqkWGl0hlMhgssJhjmHJheIiHGLA66NADWNvliuVat1tp1mtt%2BsNJhNvpzedQh0cbCtJ25UPpn2%2BjPpYuACAA%2BsRMApPHnMuP9qhkGWfVHW7n8wQuPbO3huwA6RkAdwgq%2Bj/vFRClMvV2o1Bqd64ULAg5jMb8O9JAHrMbBYJAATzfM913bTszB3LtYkPVATxAs1DinAg1gYa0CAggBaTsuEWfc0C8QRT0feFY3%2Bf4tRYJhQnLHNiGAZANU%2BRpVTVOj8SbFsEI3Dtwh3fsQAlWhaAgRpgHxQMuC5M9DgAehk7VBitVAqEOapMDYQQFH3UD8wAaT4gh0HpQThNE8TKXfDlpLk0VL0laUWB5PAAC9MG0riwIAFQMoyBKIISRLYwNtik90bIUVhknoJzXPch5zW4w4ACUfOM/zTKCylJFCqNZPk6UGHQVBHKUTB0Di1t%2BOSNFBCoV8zDMXiIFpeYlJUtSNIIBQm22blzHJITyrZNwGDfVs/Qmya330iAxQla8SpczAer6swBtoIbyRGsaEMmvaf285rFMOZSeUi%2Bhup3frBu0rbRoa8b9omt8UogAqipKzAypWj11s27aGtIR6nvNcINV0jVPI1JL4LJeKeUM4z3ogGHiLh81%2BMJBwSHBOVbkOdA%2BSYCBwlhjHEZALHiVxwR8bmogIF0smLRIa0tTwHdHVyjnXXCd1rC9H1doJomQy5HdkabNbDl0tHW1oARgEOBWjE7VAGloccoPHaomGSJR0G3XtDi589lcV83VaIDWtb3TAdYMfWyog43TbIhDLTZ20ed6k33R9txDk8/mIwsb1jTN81rbEW22AdvWDaNyNuULT5KOIMtCYafcs%2BJ5ZDjB2yJRzonT2ZhLn3q98Gs/ekfz/QDgLR81mzjdGEd8mcmggXP9xiYBqPz3vXDLuWPdZmifYdf3kSDkOrEscPm0jtWbe13WnfQF3k4LRg09LHuiZLhpTw1Qv6dQY%2B8/LnNK7Gmuv3r9TG4a5nW/d%2BGiq8KJoqYfFgCNr7L%2BP9MAQGjprdejtE6GnkiTVUQdmbAN/v/F2QDVggLAerGOkCE7OxgdaXiKoEFj3htVOUdU3xQUOMkWIql6CdWtO9YqhpvzXRUkqW6AMAg5n/jhZu1CaoEAoQ1KhNCrQdUYPKCAXcCDfU/L9Wg7CtLDXutwv%2BwAzCw1bhwZYtBODkl4H4DgWhSCoE4G4AWlgeSrHWHiQEPBSAEE0Do5YJYQDkiSHojgkhDHONMZwXgCgQBJCccYnRpA4CwBgIgFAxVkh0FiOQSgaAWDxPoHEAB2wAg0FoLI4gQSIBRD8VEUIjQAKcAcSU5gxAAIAHkojaCJBU3gKTOq1PTOUsJpAsBRC8MAM4QkgncF4FgSiRhxBdPwFOLohIhkmMwKoToeZNgOLlNUPxLIojShqR4LAfiCBohYM05YVADDAAUAANTwJgI8tSaFGIcfwQQIgxDsCkDIQQigVDqC6boLg%2BhDDGEsTYTZQTIDLFQMkWoSpOAYVqdsQ4GEADqYhaCIvTp8XsEVCoAS2XgdAwBMC8FQISYgaIsBgtPh0LozgICuAmH4f5wRZilHKHoVI6RoUMvZQUaF/RWVDH%2BdS6FPRxizlyEKtSNKGCipmCURSeheRipyIy2w0x%2BUKpwisNYGwJC6P0b4rpZiOCHFUAADniBheIkhDj0QFFwbY%2B4IIQFwIQVmOwcK8FCVoRYrj3GeM4D40gRyPH7gAJxGniNseIXBI1GiNGYC1kbSBGJMcawJwTHHOOWJEmJCylnEiSYFc5yhDDVCEAgWCqaWlxLoHyTIpawi0ArVWvxKS0lDEyQEdtCTiDhFYJsGtqTe21LzC2o81bAiLOQA8OiQyuAaEXUuw45IuAQQXRoQ4sbeD5uQPUfARjeBPOEKIcQ7zj1fLUH4v5AKjAoGBfoPAURKUQqhZkIZcKEUYQxQGXq2L0C4vJYS4lpLyXTngMsYgBEoKeVQJ4F92rbGKsMqERt5bK0TuaY4qc7AkhHmlMkY5%2BgDUpr8ca7A072xWnNZa61trkD2sdc6ixocNSuuJB6bYnqs1hN9cR7xvAjmSDDfuDQgIo1msBA1I0DqzDSEnem2wmbvUuNIG4jx/HtiGrTQEnjPr9UcDMNp4lumVN8dJekZwkggA%3D)

The goal is to benchmark a simple histogram function:

```
[[gnu::noinline]] static void histogram(int const *a, int n, int *h) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    h[a[i]]++;
}
```

The benchmark measures the average time elapsed during the histogram invocation when the input is random data, and when the input is sorted.

This is the output of this program on my machine:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++20 -O3 -march=native -o test.out && ./test.out 1000000 512 100 17
N (number of elements) = 1000000.
K (histogram size) = 512.
T (number of samples) = 100.
R (random seed) = 17.
time per element (random) : 0.751250 ns.
time per element (sorted) : 2.032259 ns.
```

I run this experiment on a 4-core sandy bridge intel processor i5-2320.
Why is the histogram algorithm more than 2 times slower when the input is sorted?

Comment: Don't post links to code on some third-party site. If the link goes dead, or you update the code then this question becomes meaningless. Post the relevant code in the question. Create a [mcve] if necessary. See [ask]

Comment: When you run it on godbolt, random is 0.4, sorted 0.3. Except for gcc 13.1 which has performance similar to yours. Are you trying it with gcc 13.1 by any chance?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular: The histogram function is shown, and the program output is sufficient to explain what's going on.  A Godbolt full-link would be better ([How are we supposed to post godbolt links now that URL shortening is blocked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319549)), just in case there's anything wrong with benchmarking methodology as well, but there's an "obvious" (to computer architecture experts) answer without even looking at the Godbolt link.

Comment: @teapot418: Godbolt might be running it on Ice Lake servers which might be doing memory-renaming, zero-latency store forwarding in some cases when the addressing-mode matches.  (Maybe even if the index value has been reloaded with the same value).  Zen 2 and Zen 4 have that, and reportedly also Ice Lake.  The OP's SnB doesn't.  https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41

Comment: If you reduce the histogram size you can reproduce on godbolt, params: 1000000 256 100 17, output: 
ime per element (random) : 0.438003 ns.
time per element (sorted) : 1.765240 ns.

Comment: Actually godbolt might execute every time on a different machine, its output is unreliable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing/reloading the same element repeatedly creates a serial dependency chain that's too long for out-of-order exec to fully overlap.

If the value-range isn't too big, the random order probably still hits in cache for most increments and is only limited by throughput, not store-forwarding latency bottlenecks.

- [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)
- [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692718/how-many-cpu-cycles-are-needed-for-each-assembly-instruction/44980899#44980899)
- https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/a-whirlwind-introduction-to-dataflow-graphs/

Some modern CPUs (Zen 2, Zen 4, and Ice Lake at least) have zero-latency store-forwarding in some cases, which may include this case where the index is reloaded with the same value.  This might be why Godbolt runs show the sorted test being faster.

- https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41#p71
- https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/bc9af3a0aaca5399824cf182f85b9e9c
- https://pvk.ca/Blog/2020/02/01/too-much-locality-for-store-forwarding/

The benchmark warms up the CPU to turbo frequency with very slow `rand()` calls, and pre-zeros the arrays because they're `std::vector<int>`, so the problems described in *[Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation)* aren't happening here, I don't think.

---

See [Methods to vectorise histogram in SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985949/methods-to-vectorise-histogram-in-simd) for a trick that helps: **use multiple arrays of counts, and sum them at the end.**  (That part can use SIMD, the actual counting can't unless you have AVX-512 for scatter/gather, and even then having multiple elements that map to the same bucket in the same vector is slower.)

This wouldn't be necessary on CPUs where memory-renaming works to get zero-latency store-forwarding in this case, except on very wide CPUs that can do more than one load + memory-destination increment per clock.

---

**If you know your data is sorted**, you could count runs of the same element and do one `+= count`, although that can easily lead to branch mispredicts unless you do something like `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(load(ptr), set1(*ptr))` ; `_mm_movemask_ps` for a couple vectors and check that `popcnt` is `< 8` elements, so runs shorter than that always branch the same way.  (The actual compare could be on `mask < 0xff`, but you'd add the popcount.  Or `31-std::countl_zero`, or `std::countr_zero(mask+1)` so you can use `tzcnt` / `bsf`.